Illustrator 2024 Grid Repeat minimum spacing limitation?
I have an Adobe Illustator 2024 project configured for 4,800 DPI, and I need to make a brick by row repeating grid that consists of a circle measuring 0.15 pt diameter and spaced 0.45 pt apart (measured from edge to edge), but my spacing values keep getting changed to 0.875 pt.
Anyone know if this is a software limitation? I can't find it documented/mentioned anywhere.
Thanks.

Have you checked snap to grid / pixel / point settings?

DPI setting in Illustrator??

There is no dpi setting in illustrator. Turn off pixel snapping. The pixel size is fixed.

I have all "snap to" options turned off. Did not make a diference. It will let me enter lower values, but automatically reverts to 0.875 in Object > Repeat > Options > Grid > Horizontal and Vertical Spacing in Grid. I need 0.2 mm spacing between the shapes.  I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve this that utilizes automation - the grid will be around 6cm x 18cm.

Does anyone have any advice for how to automate the creation of this repeating grid? Would it be best custom scripted from within Illustrator? Third-party add-on?
